# AutoHotKey too fast hotkey presses crashes script

Tags: autohotkey

Whenever I press the hotkeys fast, (as I usually do) the script then pauses and remains paused until reloaded. Nothing changes the pause, nor any of the hotkeys is working anymore. I normally press the hotkeys when the script is paused, if that could be something. Though, I've tried to press "F" and "Q" fast, and the script seems to work perfectly around 3-4 times, then stops. Suggestions?

```
#MaxHotKeysPerInterval 9999999999
#HotkeyInterval 0
SetBatchLines, -1
SetKeyDelay, 0

a = 3

loop {

reset:
a = 3
send 3
goto start

start:
sleep 575
if (a = 3) {
KeyWait, LButton, D
KeyWait, LButton
sleep 50
send, 4
a = 4
goto, start
}

else {
KeyWait, LButton, D
KeyWait, LButton
sleep 50
send, 3
a = 3
goto, start
}
$*XButton2::
Pause
goto, reset

$F::
Pause ON
goto, reset
$C::
Pause ON
goto, reset
$V::
Pause ON
goto, reset
$Q::
Pause OFF
goto, reset
$MButton::
Pause ON
goto, reset
}



!z::ExitApp
```

Comment: I didn't work with autohotkey a lot but can you try to add/increase delay between key presses? Previously when I wrote some programs in C++, while loops without delays hit the CPU to 100% instantly.

Comment: No, as it is necessary for me to click the hotkeys that fast :)

Comment: On https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47203-ahk-just-hangs-after-heavy-system-load/: "The problem only presents when the system is under maximum load - specifically, when the CPU is pegged. " I believe that's the source of the issue. You don't have to use it like that, can you just try to add a delay like 10ms between each keypress and try to see if it hangs again? This may help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I've tried, but it seems to pause whenever I do it a certain amount of times. Even if i wait a second or two between every hotkey, and tried setting the KeyDelay higher.